# Chai tea latte ok for toddler?

Tags: toddler, drinking

Is it ok for two year old to occasionally sip on a chai latte? Or should it be avoided altogether because of the caffeine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Children should avoid caffeine for as long as possible.

Chai Tea Latte contains plenty of caffeine.

Sometimes it also contains added sugar, which is another good reason to avoid it. For example, a [16oz chai tea latte from Starbucks contains 42g of sugars](http://www.starbucks.com/menu/drinks/tea/chai-latte).

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a western-ish country (US, Canada, UK, etc), chai tea is actually just spiced tea. So, if you were making your own, you could very well just skip the tea leaves and use warm milk with the Masala Chai spices added for the little one. I am a huge fan of chai tea lattes in the wintertime, and would have no qualms about doing this for my 2.5 yr old son this winter.